# How to simulate Haskell's pattern matching using visitor pattern in Java

Tags: java, haskell, generics

I am new to Java and I am trying to use visitor pattern to simulate pattern matching. For this Haskell function

```hs
getOrDefault :: Maybe a -> a -> a
getOrDefault (Just x) = const x
getOrDefault Nothing = id
```

which returns a value of type `a` (given a value of type `Maybe a` and a default value), the following Java codes work.

```java
interface Visitor<T, S> {
    S visitJust(Just<T> j);
    S visitNothing(Nothing<T> n);
}

abstract class Maybe<T> {
    public abstract <S> S accept(Visitor<T, S> v);

    public T getOrDefault(T defaultValue) {
        return this.accept(new Visitor<T, T>() {
            @Override
            public T visitJust(Just<T> j) { return j.value; }

            @Override
            public T visitNothing(Nothing<T> n) { return defaultValue; }
        });
    }
}

class Just<T> extends Maybe<T> {
    final T value;

    public Just(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public <S> S accept(Visitor<T, S> v) {
        return v.visitJust(this);
    }

}

class Nothing<T> extends Maybe<T> {
    public <S> S accept(Visitor<T, S> v) {
        return v.visitNothing(this);
    }
}
```

When I try to simulate this function that obtains the "length" of a value of type `Maybe [a]`

```hs
getLength :: Maybe [a] -> Int
getLength (Just x) = length x
getLength Nothing = -1
```

, the Java-version `getLength` I write is

```java
public int getLength() {
    return this.accept(new Visitor<List<T>, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer visitJust(Just<List<T>> j) { ... }

        @Override
        public Integer visitNothing(Nothing<List<T>> n) { ... }
    });
}
```

But it doesn't work, since `T` and `List<T>` are incompatible. How to fix this?

Comment: Aside from the question of getting this to compile: why are you trying to write it like this in Java? There's an easy way to get the length of a list: you call `list.size()`. It doesn't seem particularly useful to write in Haskell's idiom.

Comment: However, for your actual question: please show where you're declaring the `getLength()` method (as in, the containing class).

Comment: Yes I know that I can simply call `list.size()` and I agree with you. But this is just a snippet to help me understand how to use visitor pattern in Java. @AndyTurner

Comment: Sorry I don't make my question clear enough. I am declaring `getLength()` in the abstract class `Maybe<T>`. @AndyTurner

Comment: @AlfredTan You can't declare it inside `Maybe<T>` since otherwise you will have to implement `getLength()` for all `T`s, even for e.g. `Maybe<Integer>`. Length is not defined for `Maybe<T>`, but only for `Maybe<List<T>>`. Exactly like in Haskell. As suggested below, a static generic function can be defined on that more specific case.

Comment: @chi I got it. Thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare `getLength()` as a static method with its own type variable:

```
  public static <T> int getLength(Maybe<List<T>> maybe) {
    return maybe.accept(new Visitor<List<T>, Integer>() {
      @Override
      public Integer visitJust(Just<List<T>> j) { ... }

      @Override
      public Integer visitNothing(Nothing<List<T>> n) { ... }
    });
  }
```

Comment: @AlfredTan Any instance methods in `Maybe<T>` have to work for all `T`, not just for lists.